# How do I prevent my adwords URL being encoded on Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, urlencode, google-ads-api

I am having a horrible time with adwords links to my Drupal 7 site.  When the link comes in from google adwords, the URL (specifically the query string) is url encoded and makes the page 404.  Is there anyway at all to prevent Drupal from encoding the adwords url?

Been sorting through this all day today...Here's what I know.

About half of the ads work just fine. The ad is formatted like this:

http://www.example.com/land/BAG2?_kk=%7Bkeyword%7D&_kt=1bc345c5d-c3459-43451-a483-82cc74e986a7

The other half, though, get formatted like this and trigger a 404 error on the Drupal 7 site.

http://www.example.com/land/BAG2%3F_kk%3D%257Bkeyword%257D%26_kt%3D1bc345c5d-c3459-43451-a483-82cc74e986a7

At first I thought it might have been a redirect encoding the URL, but I don't think that's the case.

How are half working and half not?

Many many thanks for any ideas you might have.

Comment: Can you post an example?

Comment: edited the main question post with additional information.  Thank you!

Comment: And urldecode doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, and I had to add a flag of [NE] (no escape) to the **rewrite** rule on apache, to prevent the conversion to hexcode of those characters.